# Solving linear PDEs in canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The exercise goes:
find the canonical form of the equation and determine the general solution:
$x^2U_{xx}+2xyU_{xy}+y^2U_{yy}=y^2((x/y)^2+y^2)$

I got the form $4\eta^2U_{\eta\eta}+2\eta*U_{\eta}=\eta(1+\epsilon^2)$

But I don't know how to find it's general solution. What's exactly the method? In class, the assistant never got to that part and left it for homework. Since he went away for a trip, I can't consult him.

EDIT: Can I solve this like a Bernoulli's differential equation for function $U_{\eta}$ with a fixed $\epsilon$? On this class we've encountered for the first time with partial differential equations without a proper introduction so don't hate on me for not knowing what I presume to be rather simple.

Comment: **Hint** What type of pde is the first equation? Elliptic? Hyperbolic? Parabolic?

Comment: @unseen_rider Parabolic. Still don't have a clue. We've never talked about how to solve those, just how to find their canonical forms. Is there a method for every type?

Answer (score 1):

Solve PDE $x^2u_{xx}+2xyu_{xy}+y^2u_{yy}=x^2+y^4$.

- Particular solution is $u_p=\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{12}$
- Now we solve homogeneous equation $x^2u_{xx}+2xyu_{xy}+y^2u_{yy}=0$.

After change $\xi=\log x ,\;\eta=\log y\;$ we get 
$$u_{\xi\xi}+2u_{\xi\eta}+u_{\eta\eta}-u_\xi-u_\eta=0.$$
$${{D}_{\xi}^{2}}+2 {D_{\eta}}\, {D_{\xi}}+{{D}_{\eta}^{2}}-{D_{\xi}}-{D_{\eta}}=\left( {D_{\xi}}+{D_{\eta}}-1\right) \, \left( {D_{\xi}}+{D_{\eta}}\right)$$

Solution of $u_\xi+u_\eta=0$ is $u_1=f(\xi-\eta)$.

Solution of $u_\xi+u_\eta-u=0$ is $u_2=e^\eta g(\xi-\eta)$.

- Then, final solution is
  $$u=u_1+u_2+u_p\\=
  f(\xi-\eta)+e^\eta g(\xi-\eta)+u_p\\=f(\log x-\log y)
  +y\,g(\log x-\log y)+u_p\\=f\left(\log \frac x y \right)
  +yf\left(\log \frac xy \right)+u_p\\=F\left(\frac xy\right)+y\,G\left(\frac xy\right)+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{12}
  $$